# recursive array search for key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to do an array_search to find the associated value pair

I have an array called `$saved_data` it contains

```
Array () {
  Client_Information_1 => James
  Client_Information_2 => Doe
  ....
         }
```

I need to return the value (1st call -> James .. 2nd call -> Doe .. etc) each time I call it. the problem is it's not returning the value pair back to me. The needle contains the index "Client_Information_1" .

### my solution :

```
function recursive_array_search($saved_forms, $needle)
{
   foreach($saved_forms as $key => $value)
   {
      if ( $saved_forms[$key] === $needle )

         return $key;
   }
   return false;
}
```

### function call in my loop :

```
   $return_field = recursive_array_search($saved_data,$needle);
```

Comment: And the question / issue is....

Comment: `$saved_forms[$key]` is equal to `$value`. You're comparing the wrong thing.

Comment: it doesnt return the $key back to me it's always returning false.

Comment: What's your question ? By the way i don't see any recursion here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $key is what you're searching for and $value is what you want to return (they value at that index)

So the if statement should look like this:

```
if ( $key === $needle ) {
     return $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your function is not recursive at all or does anything else special, this'll do the same thing just fine:

```
$return_field = isset($saved_data[$needle]) ? $saved_data[$needle] : false;
```